# Unable to add Groovy SDK to Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I am trying to add a Groovy SDK to an IntelliJ Gradle project, but I am failing to to add the Groovy SDK. I am using SDKMAN but also downloaded and extracted the Groovy zip from the groovy website.

In the past it always worked without any problems but not now anymore.

This is the path I am providing to IntelliJ `/Users/dev/code/libs/groovy-2.4.10/` its what you get when you extract the groovy .zip file from the website.

[image]

**Edit:**
As suggested I tried also other groovy version down to 2.4.6 all with the same result.

Comment: Make sure you downloaded the correct version, and didn't modify it. Also ensure IntelliJ can access the path (i.e. it has sufficient privilliges on the directory).

Comment: Please try groovy 2.4.8 or groovy 2.4.9

Comment: I tried other Groovy version as well, with the same end result. Its something so obvious that is completely bewitched

Comment: This happened to me, too, earlier today! I ended up just installing 2.4.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a bug in Intellij...  Could you [raise a ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA)?

Comment: The same issue :((((

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I've upgraded to IntelliJ 2017.3.5 and I've made sure the Groovy plugin is enabled. I'm running Mac OS 10.12.6 and I've used SDKMAN to install Groovy. I've read (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170022) this is a bug in IntelliJ searching for Groovy versions with single digit major.minor.patch but I've tried this with Groovy 2.4.9 and it still won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy 2.4.10 is not recognized by intellij 2016.3.5 as well as intellij 2017.1
Groovy 2.4.8 works well with intellij 2017.1. I would guess that it works with intellij 2016.3.5 as well